# Refer to another .go file in the library

Tags: go

I am very new to Go and I have gone through [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

While it was very helpful, I'm confused about how to use a go file from within the same library.

For example, this is my structure :

```
~/src/
    hashtable/
      hashtable.go
      linkedlist.go
```

I want to use linkedlist in hashtable. What should be my directory structure and what package names should I use?

Comment: if they are in the same package you can just refer to symbols between them without any imports or anything.

Comment: Thanks! TIL not to overcomplicate things.

Comment: If you are accessing functions and methods from the same package but  different `.go` files on running the main file you should include these files in the order which you are referencing them.

Comment: @SimoEndre Can you elaborate that a bit? Some sources would be nice, also.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I think @SimoEndre is referring to a situation where you do `go run foo.go bar.go main.go`

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Yes exactly this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Go, two or more files with the same package name are considered one package, meaning everything is accessible within the namespace, including private (lowercased) and public (capitalized) symbols.

For instance, if `hashtable.go` and `linkedlist.go` share the same package name:

```
package hashtable

import (
        ...
)
```

Then both are considered the same file.

However, if they have different package name, the best practice is to keep them in separate directory.

```
// hashtable.go
package hashtable

import (
        ...
)

type Hashtable struct {}

// linkedlist.go
package linkedlist
import (
        ...
)

type Linkedlist struct {}
```

Then organizing them this way:

```
project/
├── hashtable
|   └── hashtable.go
└── linkedlist
    └── linkedlist.go
```

And for example, in `hashtable.go`, import `linkedlist` to use its public variables:

```
// hashtable.go
package hashtable

import (
        ../linkedlist
)

li = linkedlist.Linkedlist{}
```